# Is there any way to get the user SERVER banner in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I want to get the user server banner but i dont know if thats possible with discord.js is there any way i get get the banner the user sets for a server?
Im using discord.js v13, and found that the url for getting the user server banner is
`https://cdn.discordapp.com/guilds/{GuildId}/users/{MemberId}/banners/{Banner}`
I just dont know how to get the banner name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe this is possible yet. Looking at the Discord API itself, it does not appear to support server profiles yet. It isn't possible to retrieve a member's server profile banner via the API (or at least, it isn't officially possible and any way to do so isn't documented). And since the API itself doesn't support it, it's probably not possible to do this at all yet.

You can retrieve the user's global banner via API or djs, but not their server-specific banners. Unless you know the name of the banner already, the URL you provided in your question won't do you much good either.

See for yourself in the [API docs for guild members](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#guild-member-object). No server profile or banner properties to be found. Same goes for djs' `GuildMember` object as well, of course, since there is no API support. You will just have to wait for the Discord API to be updated to support this, if they plan to do so; it's been at least 4-5 months now since the feature released, though, so support may not be coming anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

Inspect element and look for div class animatedContainer. Get the url, and change size=512 to a higher number like size=2048, then save the image. The size will be maxed out at whatever resolution the image is uploaded in (so even if you put 4096, if the upload is 1080, then it'll be downloaded 1080).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).